# Django_filters - MultipleChoiceFilter with ForeignKey not shown

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm trying to filter a digital product with multiple filters. On of them includes the functionality model. So the user select a category and then, related to the category, can filter the existing products by their functionality
models.py

```
class Platform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Name')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='DigitalProduct/thumbnails')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    filter_functions = models.ManyToManyField(Functionality, verbose_name='Filter by')


class Functionality(models.Model):
    functionality = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I installed django-filter v2.4.0 and trying to add the filters.
filters.py

```
...
class PlatformFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    func = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name='category', conjoined=True)
```

Inside of my views.py function I pass the `queryset=Platform.objects.filter(category=category)` to get the correct digital products, which is working fine but the category values aren't shown in the MultipleChoiceField.

views.py

```
def platform_list(request, slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    # filter query
    f = PlatformFilter(request.GET, queryset=Platform.objects.filter(category=category))
    return render(request, 'core/platform-list.html', {
        'category': category,
        'filter': f
    })
```

So far I can see the MultipleChoiceField but no values are shown.
[image: image example]

I tried to change the field name to `field_name='category.category'` but I get an [invalid name].

Do I miss something?

Comment: Please show more parts of your `PlatformFilter` specifically it's `Meta` class, also show your view...

Comment: Ok add views.py. I haven't set a Meta class to PlatformFilter

Comment: What is the model `Platform`? You haven't shown it in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, Platform is DigitalProduct. I had wrong name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if one would want to use a `MultipleChoiceFilter` they would have to provide the choices which you don't hence no choices are displayed.

Furthermore since `category` is a `ForeignKey` then instead of using a `MultipleChoiceFilter` you should be using a [`ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` [django-filter docs]](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#modelmultiplechoicefilter) instead:

```
class PlatformFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    func = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(field_name='category', queryset=Category.objects.all(), conjoined=True)
```

Comment: NIce, works so for. But how can I get the filter_functions from the category I selected? I want to filter by filter_functions. Do you know?